# Button IsPressed Trigger Not Working

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, triggers

I have a button with an undo image inside it.
I want the button to make the border appear when user clicks (ispressed) the button.

```
<Button Margin="0,7,12,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Width="23">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="20" Width="20" Source="/Images/Undo.png">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Image">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                </Button>
```

But its not working at all.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: @jstreet can you please repost your solution. I was very busy sorry and could not mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following changes to your style: 1) moved triggers within `ControlTemplate`; 2) assigned `x:Name` to `Border` so it can be referenced in the trigger; 3) defined `BorderBrush`.

```
    <Button Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="75" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border x:Name="b0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="b0" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="b0" Value="Blue"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="20" Width="20" Source="/Images/Undo.jpg">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </Button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the button template sets the border thickness to 1 directly, ignoring the border thickness attribute of the button element itself. You're successfully changing a value that isn't used.

You will have to copy and modify the button template if you want to change the border thickness.